# Why does NSOperation disable automatic key-value observing?

Tags: key-value-observing, nsoperation

When working with a custom `NSOperation` subclass I noticed that the automatic key-value observing is disabled by the `[NSOperation automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey]` class method (which returns `NO` at least for some key paths). Because of that the code inside of `NSOperation` subclasses is littered by manual calls to `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChange…`, as visible in many code samples on the web.

Why does `NSOperation` do that? With automatic KVO support people could simply declare properties for the operation lifecycle flags (`isExecuting` etc.) and trigger the KVO events through the accessors, ie. the following code:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
finished = YES;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
```

…could be replaced by this:

```
[self setIsExecuting:NO];
[self setIsFinished:YES];
```

Is there a catch somewhere? I just overrode the `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` to return `YES` and things seem to work fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the kvo keys don't match the standard conventions. Normally one has methods like `-isExecuting` and `-setExecuting:`, where the key path is `@"executing"`. In the case of NSOperation, the key path is `@"isExecuting"` instead.

The other possibility is that most NSOperations don't actually have a method named `-setIsExecuting:` to change that value. Instead, they base the executing/finished flags on other internal state. In this case, one absolutely needs to use the explicit willChange/didChange notifications. For example, if I have an NSOperation that wraps an NSURLConnection, I may have 2 ivars, one named `data` that holds the downloaded data, and one named `connection` which holds the NSURLConnection, and I may implement the getters like so:

```
- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    return (connection != nil);
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return (data != nil && connection == nil);
}
```

Now my `-start` method can use

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // doesn't affect executing, but is used later
connection = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self] retain];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
```

to start executing, and

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[connection cancel];
[connection release];
connection = nil;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
```

to finish.

Comment: Kevin, i believe your example is inconsistent and should nil connection after cancel/release. Otherwise, isFinished won't return YES.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that overriding `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` appears to work, but I personally forgo the `isExecuting` and `isFinished` properties altogether and instead define `executing` and `finished` properties, which, as Kevin suggests, is more consistent with modern conventions:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isFinished)  BOOL finished;
```

I then write custom setters for these two properties, which do the necessary `isExecuting` and `isFinished` notifications:

```
- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

This yields:

- a more customary `BOOL` property declaration;
- custom setters satisfy the strange notifications that `NSOperation` requires; and
- I can now just use the `executing` and `finished` setters throughout my operation implementation, without littering my code with notifications.

I must confess that I like the elegance of overriding `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey`, but I just worry about unintended consequences.

---

Note, if doing this in iOS 8 or Yosemite, you will also have to explicitly synthesize these properties in your `@implementation`:

```
@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are talking about NSOperation can not use automatic KVO. But I just try to verify that, therefore it can use KVO.

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"isReady"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
          context:&ctxKVO_CSDownloadOperation];

[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"isExecuting"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
          context:&ctxKVO_CSDownloadOperation];

[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"isFinished"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
          context:&ctxKVO_CSDownloadOperation];

[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"isCancelled"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
          context:&ctxKVO_CSDownloadOperation];

...

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == &ctxKVO_CSDownloadOperation) {
        NSLog(@"KVO: %@", keyPath);
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

The result:

```
2017-08-02 14:29:58.831 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isReady : 1
2017-08-02 14:29:58.831 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isReady
2017-08-02 14:29:58.831 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isExecuting : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.831 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isExecuting
2017-08-02 14:29:58.831 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isFinished : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.832 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isFinished
2017-08-02 14:29:58.832 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isCancelled : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.832 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isCancelled
2017-08-02 14:29:58.832 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isReady : 1
2017-08-02 14:29:58.832 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isReady
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isExecuting : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isExecuting
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isFinished : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isFinished
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isCancelled : 0
2017-08-02 14:29:58.833 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isCancelled
2017-08-02 14:29:58.834 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isReady : 1
2017-08-02 14:29:58.834 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] KVO: isReady
2017-08-02 14:29:58.834 CSDownloader[77366:5089399] isExecuting : 0
```

So I am really confused about this question and answers...

Answer (score -3):

The `NSOperationQueue` is not observing `isFinished` or `isExecuting`, it is observing `finished` and `executing`.

`isFinished` is simply the the synthesized get accessor for the property `finished`. Automatic key-value observing notifications will be sent for this property unless your subclass has specifically opted out of automatic KVO notifications by implementing `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` or `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversOf<Key>` to return NO. If you have not opted out of automatic KVO notifications, you do not need to perform manual notifications using `will/DidChangeValueForKey:`. In your case, you were sending manual notifications for `isFinished` and `isExecuting`, which are not the key paths that `NSOperationQueue` observes.

#### TL;DR: These aren't the key paths that NSOperationQueue is looking for.

[image: These are not the key paths you are looking for]

`executing` and `finished` are the correct key paths, and they should be sending automatic KVO notifications.

If you are **truly paranoid** about KVO and want to send notifications for the get accessor key paths such as `isFinished`, register your property as a dependency of the key path:

```
+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished {
    NSSet   *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"finished"];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't use your Jedi mind tricks on us. `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` actually _do_ observe `isFinished`/`isExecuting` (as correctly described in the documentation). [This is easily demonstrated.](https://github.com/robertmryan/Operation-Test-Objective-C) You appear to  incorrectly infer from the `finished` and `executing` properties in `NSOperation.h` that `NSOperation`/`NSOperationQueue` internally must be observing `finished` and `executing` KVN. The `isFinished`/`isExecuting` KVN is not for the "paranoid", but rather is essential for anyone using use asynchronous operations.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on compliance with key value coding and key value observing. The correct way to be key value observing compliant in this scenario is to register the property as a dependency of the getter key path. If you assert that KVO or NSOperation is broken or a "bad API", file a bug.

Comment: This is the third time you've asked me to file a bug because `NSOperation` behaves precisely as documented in the _Concurrency Programming Guide._ Lol. Sure, it's disappointing that Apple's long-standing KVN convention for `NSOperation` requires this non-standard manual change notification, and if it bothers you that it doesn't conform to traditional KVO-compliance, you should file a bug. But until Apple changes it, please stop advising people to not do the appropriate `isFinished`/`isExecuting` notifications for `NSOperation`, because it causes problems for concurrent/asynchronous operations.

Comment: "Sure, it's disappointing that Apple's long-standing KVN convention for NSOperation requires this non-standard manual change notification" This is absolutely not true, but if you have a problem with the documentation or the API, file a bug. If *you* feel that NSOperation is not KVO compliant - which is effectively what you are asserting - file a bug.

Comment: "stop advising people to not do the appropriate isFinished/isExecuting notifications". I am advising people to use KVO *correctly* and when overriding public readonly properties with writable properties, to *register the dependent key paths*, NOT send manual change notifications. Again, this is covered in the KVO documentation.

Comment: Good addition of the key path dependencies pattern to get the required `isFinished` (and other) notifications.