# Calling method on NSOperation subclass from another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've made an `NSOperation` subclass with a start method containing a call to a method which has a completion block. The completion block contains code which marks the operation as finished (KVO). That block seems to typically be executed on the main thread (rather than my NSOperationQueue's background thread).

What I'm seeing is that the operation doesn't appear to ever get marked as finished, and I assume this is because of the threading issue. Is there some way I can get the KVO calls to occur on the correct thread, and thus allow my operation to terminate properly?

The method with the completion block is 3rd party code, so I'd prefer not to have to alter it.

EDIT: Here's the relevant code.

```
-(void)start
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    NSData *mutableData = [NSData thisIsWhereMyDataIsCreated];

    [self.peripheral writeData:mutableData characteristicUUID:[CBUUID transmitCharacteristicUUID] serviceUUID:[CBUUID serviceUUID] completion:^(CBCharacteristic * _Nullable characteristic, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [self markAsFinished];
    }];
}

-(void)markAsFinished
{
    NSLog(@"Finishing op...");
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    self.onComplete();
}
```

And it's the `markAsFinished:` method that's being called on the main thread, via the `completion block` for the writeData... method.

Comment: Is this your issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10423127/653513

Comment: @rokjarc No it isn't... I'm already sending the KVO notifications manually.

Comment: Code? code code code.

Comment: @Avi: Relevant code added :)

Comment: Why the downvote? o_O

Comment: You don't want to dispatch back to your queue, because that can easily lead to deadlocks.  If it's a serial queue, it _will_ lead to deadlocks.

There's no particular reason why calling `markAsFinished` should have threading issues.  There's more going on.

Comment: @Avi Well the call to markAsFinished occurs on the main thread, while the NSOperation is on a background thread. This is surely a problem? If the KVO notifications aren't being sent on the same thread that they're being listened for, from what I've read, I won't get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Observers are called synchronously, so they are always called from the same thread the KVO notification is posted from.  You don't specify a thread  or queue when you register an observer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113409/discussion-between-darren-black-and-avi).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, I think.. did you ever come up with a solution to this? Thanks! @DarrenBlack

Comment: @Laura Sorry for the delay here, but I added an answer that was deleted by the admins. The content was this: "@Avi was correct; my issue had nothing to do with threading here. I'd forgotten to implement the getters for the isExecuting and isFinished properties."

Comment: Hopefully this helps, since it was so long ago that I can't remember the details of this :)