# NSOperation KVO isFinished

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, nsoperation

Im trying to subclass a NSOperation, and read some sample from,
they say: when the task finished, using KVO of NSOperation, to finish the operation,
code here:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"]
finished = YES;
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
```

then isFinished get called

```
- (BOOL) isFinished{
    return(finished);
}
```

anyone could explain this to me? why isFinished gets called, will the isFinished finish the operation? as I understanded, do KVO manually need [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"]; and I didnt see code like addobserver: and observeValueForKeyPath:

I write

```
 -(void)call
{
     [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isVip"];
     [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isVip"];
}

-(void)isVip
{
    NSLog(@"Im vip");
}
```

isVip is not called when do [self call];

Answer (score 2):

The `NSOperationQueue` implementation will observe the "isFinished" property of your operation (using KVO) so it knows when to remove it from the queue. `isFinished` is most likely being called by internal Apple code after it has been told of the change to its value.

Comment: how and when does the dealloc func of operation be called?

Comment: `dealloc` will be called when the operation's reference count hits 0, i.e. when nobody has an owning reference to it.

Comment: cool, man, I give operation a observer and when isFinished, I call release and dealloc occurs. many thanks,

Comment: BTW, you mentioned NSOperationQueue observe isFinished, and apple code call isFinished, is it a chain that, queue observes the op finished, then it tells apple code to call isFinished, if yes, I simply run the op by [op start] without a queue, isFinished gets called as normal. and if remove didChangeValueForKey, isFinished not called, and op cant be released

Answer (score 1):

Adding to quellish answer, this is how you would override executing, finished, cancelled.

```
//.m
@interface MyOperation ()  //class extension, make these otherwise read-only properties read-write, we must synthesize
@property(atomic, assign, readwrite, getter=isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property(atomic, assign, readwrite, getter=isFinished) BOOL finished;
@property(atomic, assign, readwrite, getter=isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;
@end

@implementation CoreLocationOperation
@synthesize executing, finished, cancelled;

+ (BOOL)automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey {
  return YES;
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsCancelled {
  NSSet *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"cancelled"];
  return result;
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting {
  NSSet *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"executing"];
      return result;
}

 + (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished {
    NSSet *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"finished"];
   return result;
 }


- (void)start {
 //..
  //You can use self.executing = YES; (note we can change executing which would otherwise be read-only because we synthesized our own ivar.
  [self setExecuting:YES];
...
}

- (void)cancel {
//..
  //super will change the properties executing/finished for us or we can do it manually
  [super cancel];
...

}
    @end
```

I think this is clearer than having

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:_NSURLOperationIsFinished];
    [self setIsFinished:YES];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:_NSURLOperationIsFinished];
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you should not need to do manual KVO notifications. For an `NSOperation` subclass KVO notifications should be sent automatically unless your class has opted out of automatic KVO notifications by implementing `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey` or `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversOf<Key>` to return NO.

`NSOperation` subclasses are not very useful unless they are added to an `NSOperationQueue`. When an operation is added to a queue, the queue uses KVO to observe the properties that indicate state changes, such as `finished`, `executing`, `cancelled`, etc. Note that these are not `isFinished`, `isExecuting`, or `isCancelled` - those are the names of the synthesized get accessors for those properties.

In your question you include this code:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"]
finished = YES;
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
```

What you're doing here is sending manual KVO notifications *for the get accessors*, not the properties being observed. Instead, this would accomplish what you seem to be trying to do:

```
[self setFinished:YES];
[self setExecuting:NO];
```

Rather than accessing instance variables directly, use the accessor methods. This will correctly send automatic change notifications for these properties.

If you are **truly paranoid** about KVO and want to send notifications for the get accessor key paths such as `isFinished`, register your property as a dependency of the key path:

```
+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished {
    NSSet   *result = [NSSet setWithObject:@"finished"];
    return result;
}
```

[Registering dependencies is part of KVO compliance.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)

Comment: This is not correct. I'd refer readers our discussion in the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25953779/1271826.

Comment: The author's original approach of manually invoking the KVO notification methods is attempting to manage dependencies between key paths. KVO has a mechanism for doing this, that should be used as a first resort.

Comment: Good addition of the key path dependencies pattern to get the required `isFinished` (and other) notifications.