# why use "willChangeValueForKey:" in SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

There is a class named "SDWebImageDownloaderOperation" which has the following method in SDWebImageView lib.

```
- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

however, rs does not override `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` and don't implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` methods,so what is the purpose of writing

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]
```

and

```
 [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key reason here is that `SDWebImageDownloaderOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation` and this class doesn't work with normal `KVO` notification like all the other classes.
This operation performs some task on background, so you need to inform the operating system when your operation is finished and when is still running.

Apple suggests [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide.pdf) to explicitly call `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey`.

If you are looking for a better explanation why `NSOPerations` don't have normal KVO you can read this answer [Why does NSOperation disable automatic key-value observing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573236/why-does-nsoperation-disable-automatic-key-value-observing)